# Convert any type of videos to MP4 php without ffmpeg

Tags: php, html, video, ffmpeg

I have a website on which I allow users to upload videos. But I'm using the HTML5 video tag and only MP4 videos can be played. So I want to convert any type of video to MP4. I'm on a shared hosting account so I can't have FFMPEG or anything else installed on the server. Is there another way to convert videos without these tools?

Comment: Ffmpeg is a very robust project. Hardly you do not go use it or use VLC. In this case, I recommend using an API. https://cloudconvert.com/api

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Thank you. I tried to understand how to use it but I didn't figure out how. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't installed FFMPEG then it's going to be challenging to solve this in your shared hosting environment.

Your best bet would be to look at a solution that allows you to offload the actual processing - either using something like [Azure Media Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-encode-asset), [AWS Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/), [Ooyala](http://www.ooyala.com/video-hosting), or [ZenCoder](https://zencoder.com/en/). There are also simple [hosted FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpegasaservice.com/) services (though not sure how established/reliable these are)

Comment: Okay thank you. I will check them

Comment: Will you be able to help me setting up one of them ?

Comment: would suggest following something like this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-get-started for Azure or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html for AWS. Once you decide which to go with, specific questions here should get you help

Comment: Is it one  that you recommend the most?

Comment: if you want to get hands on, then Azure or AWS give you most control, but I'd suggest something like http://www.ooyala.com/try-ooyala and see if that works for you (includes player, analytics etc, with a 30 day trial).